# Error on INSERT INTO command with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have some weird bug when trying to mock my database.

First, here is my User model (with default timestamp because I didnt add anything to options):

```js
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../db");

const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // or maybe Type STRING?
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  first_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  number_of_answers: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
  }
});


module.exports = User;
```

I already have one user that I had inserted by Signup endpoint:
[Screenshot from psql - SELECT * FROM users;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAlHj.png)

Now, I am trying to INSERT INTO users and I made a sql file with Mockaroo. Here is example of one line, and error that I am getting when I try to run this command.

[psql error on INSERT INTO command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNiK.png)

Does anyone know what is a problem here and how can I insert user in colletion via psql.

If you want to know how my endpoint for signup works, here is my code:

```js
// User Signup
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Crypting password
    const hashedPw = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12);
    const results = await User.create({
      first_name: req.body.firstName,
      last_name: req.body.lastName,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPw,
    });
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "User saved to database",
      data: {
        results: results,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out that I need to put attributes in between "".. So it would be like this below..

```
INSERT INTO users ("id", ...,"createdAt" ..) VALUES ("idValue", ...);
```